# where to download yum-utils-1.1.16-21.el5.noarch.rpm?

Tags: installation, yum, redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm

I am trying to install yum-utils package,yum-utils-1.1.16-21.el5.noarch.rpm, for RedHat linux. However, I could not find where to download it form. Anyone has any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find such package on redhat network https://rhn.redhat.com/
If you have no password you have to use Centos.

Comment: Hi I installed the yum-utils by commadn "yum -y yum-utils.noarch"from red hat network. Thanks,